# Showing an Alert conditionally, and only once

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, alert

On a PHP page, when submitting a form, I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

- check if field A is not empty (has at least one number in it)
- check if field B IS empty
- popup an alert to indicate field B is blank, and prevent the form from being submitted
- have that alert appear only once
- if the form is being submitted for a second time under the same conditions, allow it to go through

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: what about the HTML5 'required' attribute?

Comment: Are you intending on doing this on the client, using JavaScript, or on the server with PHP?

Comment: Prefer a javascript or Jquery script to do this on the client side.

Comment: You need both client facing and server side validation, either have just php or have php and js, having just js can be manipulated.

On top of that, can you post the code you have? We don't do it for you, we help you with what you have.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin... That's the problem :(

Comment: @MacGyver_97 are you talking about client side validation?

Comment: Then you are mad man, you cannot make client side validation without server side validation too, the client can modify your code and just send the data he wants too to your server ... NEVER FORGET : **NEVER TRUST USER INPUT** --- Now, you just have to make the verification in php and if there is a problem, just echo some `<script>alert('error here ...')</script>`

Comment: @MacGyver_97 I agree on Bob0t's comment... you cannot(and you should not) make client side validation without server side validation too.

Comment: There are countless tutorials and javascript plugins and server side libraries to help with validation. You should do some serious research first before coming here. Then when you have problems with live code come back

Answer (score 1):

**If you are talking about client side validation**, then you can try for HTML5 `required` attribute for this:

```
<form>
    A:<input type="text" name="A" required><br/>
    B:<input type="text" name="B" required><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

here, `required` attribute in `input` specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

This link will help you:[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

**For server side validation**, [here is a good example on how we can achieve server side validation in HTML form using PHP.](http://w3epic.com/how-to-validate-form-with-php-server-side-validation/)

Comment: Well, this doesn't exactly address the issue about the Alert only appearing once, and ONLY when field B is empty (field A should have something in it). The Alert acts as a reminder. If the person still submits the form after the first alert appears, the form can be submitted anyway.

Comment: @MacGyver_97 as I said in comments, you should use server-side validation for this.editing my question..wait